# How to convert a pyspark column(pyspark.sql.column.Column) to pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an use case to map the elements of a pyspark column based on a condition.
Going through this documentation [pyspark column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.html), i could not find a function for pyspark column to execute map function.

So tried to use the pyspark dataFrame map function, but not being able to convert the pyspark column to a dataframe

Note: The reason i am using the pyspark column is because i get that as an input from a library(Great expectations) which i use.

```
@column_condition_partial(engine=SparkDFExecutionEngine)
def _spark(cls, column, ts_formats, **kwargs):
    return column.isin([3])
    # need to replace the above logic with a map function
    # like column.map(lambda x: __valid_date(x))
```

_spark function arguments are passed from the library

What i have,

A pyspark column with timestamp strings

What i require,

A Pyspark column with boolean(True/False) for each element based on validating the timestamp format

example for dataframe,

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: __valid_date(x)).toDF()
```

__valid_date function returns True/False

So, i either need to convert the pyspark column into dataframe to use the above map function or is there any map function available for the pyspark column?

Comment: You can add an extra column with `withColumn` and logic will be based on `__valid_date` UDF. Finally you can select this newly created column will give you a new Dataframe.

Comment: @snithish can you explain how i can proceed with the variable say (timestamp_column) of type pyspark.sql.column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to return a column object that the framework will use for validation.
I have not used *Great expectations*, but maybe you can define an UDF for transforming your column. Something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

valid_date_udf = udf(lambda x: __valid_date(x), T.BooleanType())

@column_condition_partial(engine=SparkDFExecutionEngine)
def _spark(cls, column, ts_formats, **kwargs):
    return valid_date_udf(column)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example @fskj . The problem here is i do not have the dataframe object and i get only the pyspark column.

Here in the _spark function (updated the question) , the arguments are passed by the library

Comment: You're welcome. I have updated my answer to reflect your added code snippet.

Comment: Thanks @fskj ! UDF function worked for me

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of *Great Expectations*!